# How to remove an unwanted git branch "loop"

Tags: git

While interactive rebasing and merging on a branch I "managed" to create the following branch loop:

```
---a-----------g--h----m--n---
    \--b--c--d--e--f--/
```

- The b, c, d, e and f commits were done during debug.
- The g and h commits resulted from interactive rebasing
- The m commit resulted a merge ...
- I would like to keep the a-g-h-m-n history and get rid of the -b-c-d-e-f history. How could I do it?

Let me clarify, my goal here is to eliminate the **-b-c-d-e-f-** history line,  keep the **m** merge and end up with the single line **-a-g-h-m-n-** history.

Comment: You mean, you want to get rid of all the changes introduced by the merge?

Comment: Git is a DAG - directed acyclic graph.  No loops exist in Git.  This looks to be like a normal merge history.

Comment: It is a normal history but the b-c-d-e-f portion of the history is equivalent to the g-h one and I would like to remove the b-c-d-e-f one.

Comment: Do you want to keep the m merge but get rid of the commit history within that branch? But still keep the changes?

Comment: Yes, I would like to keep the m merge and get single history line as ---a-----------g--h----m--n---

Answer (score 0):

> *I would like to keep the a-g-h-m-n history and get rid of the -b-c-d-e-f history. ...the b-c-d-e-f portion of the history is equivalent to the g-h one and I would like to remove the b-c-d-e-f one How could I do it?*

```
---a-----------g--h----m--n---
    \--b--c--d--e--f--/
```

I'm not fully convinced this is a good idea. If a-g-h-m and a-b-c-d-e-f-m were equivalent the merge would not have happened. You can look at the differences with `git diff h f` and decide.

But here's how to do it.

You need to eliminate the `m` merge. You want something like this:

```
---a-----------g--h----n
    \--b--c--d--e--f
```

To do that you need to move master back to `h` and then graft `n` onto `h`. Branch heads (`master` is a branch head) are moved with `git reset --hard`. Grafting is done with `git cherry-pick`.

- `git checkout master`
- `git reset --hard h` moves `master` back to `h`.
- `git cherry-pick n` repatches `n` onto `h`.

Note that this will result in `n` having a new commit id. This will cause problems for other contributors if `n` was pushed. Anyone who has `n` will get an error next time they try to push or pull and will need to `git pull --force`.

Comment: Re. "I'm not fully convinced this is a good idea",   when I look the changes in commit 'm', I get a message that both contents are equal.  Thus I conclude that 'b-c-d-e-f' == 'g-h'.

Comment: @budan If you're using something like `git log -p m`, I believe merge commits don't show any change unless there was a conflict. Try `git diff h f` instead.

Comment: In fact, it's worse than that, `git log -1 -p <mergecommit>` shows nothing *even if there was a conflict*. You need `git log -1 -m -p <mergecommit>` to get two diffs, or `git log -1 -m --first-parent -p <mergecommit>` to get a diff against just the first parent.

Comment: Thank you guy.  This is helpful.

Comment: Be careful when doing this if the latest commit has been pushed to a remote repository. You are changing the branch history which will impact other users.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove all the commits from the branch the simplest solution is to use `git revert <commit>`.

The use of revert is described well at the page [Undoing changes](http://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes).

Using revert means that the history remains unchanged which is particularly useful if you have pushed the code to a remote repository.

Comment: Can someone explain please why this answer was down voted? Is my understanding of `git revert` wrong?

Comment: I agree that `revert` is safer and often a better option for a shared repo. If I had to guess why this got DV'd: the OP wants to get rid of the actual history, not revert content. The content is believed to be the same (though I don't think it is) so there's nothing to revert.