# How to eliminate an irrelevant part of change history in git

Tags: git, rebase

This is a reiteration of my previous question since it was not a clear one.

I have the following git change history tree:

```
---a-----------g--h----m--n---
    \--b--c--d--e--f--/
```

I got this by:

1. Applying commits **b**, **c**, **d**, **e** and **f**, which resulted from testing of my work.
2. Then I interactively re-based commits **b**, **c**, & **d** and **e** & **f** into commits **g** & **h**, respectively, onto commit **a**.
3. I made additional changes following commit **f** and merged them into the re-based branch as commit **m**.
4. After the merge I made more changes, resulting as commit **n**.

I then realised that the relevant change history from **a** to **n** is the -**g**-**h**-**m**- line and not the **-b-c-d-e-f-m-** one.

Thus I want to eliminated the latter and end up with the following change history line:

**--a--g--h--m--n--**

How do I go about it?

Comment: You can drop the other commits. I use the interactive rebase when rebasing *is* relevant and safe.

Comment: You _can't_ end up with that history line, which would imply that the branch never really happened.  Actually, I can't follow your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove an unwanted git branch "loop"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771020/how-to-remove-an-unwanted-git-branch-loop)

Comment: Edit the original question instead of reposting.